# herokuでrails5のチャットアプリの公開

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websocket

以下のリンクを参考にlocalではrails5のチャットアプリを作成できました。
http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/aec75fab42804287d71b

herokuでも動作させようと思いいろいろやってみましたがうまくいきません。
1日かかっても検討がつかない為質問させていただきました。
何か助言をいただけないでしょうか。

herokuで追加でやったことは
・rediscloudをアドオンで追加
・/config/redis/cable.yml のproduction:urlをENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]に変更（なんとなく）

chromeのnetworkでは以下のようなエラー

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://rails5chatxxxx.herokuapp.com/cable' failed: 
>   WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

herokuのlogでは
アプリ起動時

> 2015-12-23T05:24:32.308667+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
>   2015-12-23T05:24:32.308689+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.0.beta1 application starting in production on ttp://0.0.0.0:43766
>   2015-12-23T05:24:32.308690+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>   2015-12-23T05:24:32.308691+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>   2015-12-23T05:24:32.380698+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: `serve_static_files` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1.
>   2015-12-23T05:24:32.380702+00:00 app[web.1]: Please use `public_file_server.enabled = true` instead.
>   2015-12-23T05:24:32.380703+00:00 app[web.1]:  (called from block in tsort_each at /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228)
>   2015-12-23T05:24:32.864256+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
>   2015-12-23T05:24:32.864271+00:00 app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
>   2015-12-23T05:24:32.864445+00:00 app[worker.1]:
>   2015-12-23T05:24:32.864465+00:00 app[worker.1]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
>   2015-12-23T05:24:33.073776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
>   2015-12-23T05:24:33.050125+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma 2.15.3 starting...
>   2015-12-23T05:24:33.050130+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
>   2015-12-23T05:24:33.050131+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
>   2015-12-23T05:24:33.050132+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:43766
>   2015-12-23T05:24:33.598097+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
>   2015-12-23T05:24:33.577983+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1

その後以下の様なログが繰り返されます

> 2015-12-23T05:31:46.633164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/cable" host=rails5chatxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=00ff5924-89b8-4fbc-b738-4ffa0bf84981 fwd="119.83.217.68" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
>   2015-12-23T05:32:07.671155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/cable" host=rails5chat.herokuapp.com request_id=b925dc28-e0b4-40ac-b0e2-79a4f142e6b0 fwd="119.83.217.68" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
>   2015-12-23T05:32:11.828813+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/cable" for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:11 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:11.831413+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:11 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:11.831491+00:00 app[web.1]: Request origin not allowed: ttps://rails5chatxxxx.herokuapp.com
>   2015-12-23T05:32:11.831555+00:00 app[web.1]: Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:11 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:15.689969+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/cable" for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:15 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:15.693371+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:15 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:15.693418+00:00 app[web.1]: Request origin not allowed: ttps://rails5chatxxxx.herokuapp.com
>   2015-12-23T05:32:15.693490+00:00 app[web.1]: Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:15 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:16.353150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/cable" host=rails5chatxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=56c96769-e94b-49f2-bd45-d69fdb850058 fwd="119.83.217.68" dyno=web.1 connect=15ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
>   2015-12-23T05:32:38.642087+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/cable" for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:38 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:38.644988+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:38 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:38.645033+00:00 app[web.1]: Request origin not allowed: ttps://rails5chatxxxx.herokuapp.com
>   2015-12-23T05:32:38.645078+00:00 app[web.1]: Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:38 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:41.832172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/cable" host=rails5chatxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=7027966d-1bf0-4624-ba92-1177c570a622 fwd="119.83.217.68" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
>   2015-12-23T05:32:45.285005+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/cable" for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:45 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:45.287925+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:45 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:45.287980+00:00 app[web.1]: Request origin not allowed: ttps://rails5chatxxxx.herokuapp.com
>   2015-12-23T05:32:45.288046+00:00 app[web.1]: Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 119.83.217.68 at 2015-12-23 05:32:45 +0000
>   2015-12-23T05:32:45.717113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/cable" host=rails5chatxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=8ef144f2-f5f4-4e2a-9ae2-0ca015df58f5 fwd="119.83.217.68" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0

※httpをttpに変更してあります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リモートで動かす時には、Action CableがWebSocketの接続元の制限をしているようです (`Request origin not allowed`)。当方では、[`config/environments/production.rb`で`config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins`を設定する](https://github.com/JunichiIto/campfire/commit/4b4e726f2b541d0f43ae019c6fc121df6f8fbc02)ことでチャットができるようになりました。

Comment: 無事herokuで公開することができました。ありがとうございます!
web socketは全然わからないのでrails5に入る前に勉強しておきます。